# Keep getting this review warning Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I submit to appstore review team and got this warning:

> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access their contacts but does not clarify the use of the contacts in the applicable purpose string.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise the relevant purpose string in your app’s Info.plist file to specify why the app is requesting access to the user's contacts. You can modify your app's Info.plist file using the property list editor in Xcode.
>
> To help users understand why your app is requesting access to their personal data, all permission request alerts in your app should specify how your app will use the requested feature.

I already put contact usage description in my info.plist but review team reply that warning again.

[image: contact usage description]

How to correct this so it can pass appstore review team ?

Comment: It sounds like they want something better than your current message. Also note that your photo library privacy message is pointless too. The user knows you require access to the photo library. Your message needs to explain *why* you need access.

Answer (score 3):

as @rmaddy said you have to give better message in `info.plist` file as per your requirements.

i also face same issue but i have solved using below messages. hope it will help you.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>You need to provide camera access to scanning the QR Code.</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>You need to provide photo album access to upload profile image.</string>

<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>You need to provide contact access to link and manage contacts.</string>
```

**above code is just example and you can edit and write your description as per your requirements.**